# Azure is blocking request that come from the same server

Tags: asp.net, azure, security, umbraco, azure-web-app-service

## Context

Umbraco CMS website runs on Azure as App Service

### Scheduled Publishing

One of the Umbraco functionalities is to allow to publish content on a given time. The publish functionality makes a HTTP call to same web site (or a different server but same website in load balanced environment).

#### API call url:

```
http://sample-site-umbraco.azurewebsites.net/umbraco/RestServices/ScheduledPublish/Index
```

### IP Security

Due to client requirements, access to the site is restricted to a given list of IP addresses. This task is being completed with IP Security restriction in web.config.

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" />
  </requestFiltering>
  <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
    <!-- "clear" removes all upstream restrictions -->
    <clear />

    <!-- permit the loopback address  -->
    <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true" />

    ...
    ...
    ...

    <!-- domain Name for Scheduled Publishing -->
    <add allowed="true" domainName="sample-site-umbraco.azurewebsites.net"/>
  </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

## Problem

When IP Security is **turned on**, the HTTP call to publish **API is being blocked** as not white listed one.

#### API call response Status Code and Content:

```
404 - NotFound
"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

[Problem Thread](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/85795-scheduled-publishing-doesnt-work) on our.umbraco.com

## Fix attempts

### Adding domainName to the list of allowed entries

```
<!-- domain Name for Scheduled Publishing -->
<add allowed="true" domainName="sample-site-umbraco.azurewebsites.net"/>
```

This solution doesn't work. Calls are still being blocked.

## Question

How this can be fixed? Is there any functionality that can be override?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the solution. I think it will work.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871795/restrict-azure-appservice-website-to-a-domain) on stackoverflow and it worked :)

## Solution

Solution is to add ALL outbound IP addresses into System.WebServer > Security > ipSecurity > [List].

[image: Azure App Service Outbound Ip Addresses]

Outbound Ip Addresses are comma separated list of ips.
You need to add all of them to the WhiteList in web.config.

### Drawback

I'm not sure if the list of Outbound Ips is static and will not change in the future...